# Why word embedding technique works

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I have look into some word embedding techniques, such as

1. CBOW: from context to single word. Weight matrix produced used as embedding vector
2. Skip gram: from word to context (from what I see, its acutally word to word, assingle prediction is enough). Again Weight matrix produced used as embedding

Introduction to these tools would always quote "cosine similarity", which says words of similar meanning would convert to similar vector.

But these methods all based on the 'context', account only for words around a target word. I should say they are 'syntagmatic' rather than 'paradigmatic'. So why the close in distance in a sentence indicate close in meaning? I can think of many counter example that frequently occurs

1. "Have a good day". (good and day are vastly different, though close in distance).
2. "toilet" "washroom" (two words of similar meaning, but a sentence contains one would unlikely to contain another)

Any possible explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of "why" isn't a great fit for StackOverflow, but some thoughts:

The essence of word2vec & similar embedding models may be **compression**: the model is forced to predict neighbors using **far less internal state** than would be required to remember the entire training set. So it has to force similar words together, in similar areas of the parameter space, and force groups of words into various useful relative-relationships.

So, in your second example of 'toilet' and 'washroom', even though they rarely appear together, they do tend to appear around the same neighboring words. (They're synonyms in many usages.) The model tries to predict them both, to similar levels, when typical words surround them. And vice-versa: when they appear, the model should generally predict the same sorts of words nearby.

To achieve that, their vectors must be nudged quite close by the iterative training. The only way to get 'toilet' and 'washroom' to predict the same neighbors, through the shallow feed-forward network, is to corral their word-vectors to nearby places. (And further, to the extent they have slightly different shades of meaning – with 'toilet' more the device & 'washroom' more the room – they'll still skew slightly apart from each other towards neighbors that are more 'objects' vs 'places'.)

Similarly, words that are formally antonyms, but easily stand-in for each-other in similar contexts, like 'hot' and 'cold', will be somewhat close to each other at the end of training. (And, their various nearer-synonyms will be clustered around them, as they tend to be used to describe similar nearby paradigmatically-warmer or -colder words.)

On the other hand, your example "have a good day" probably doesn't have a giant influence on either 'good' or 'day'. Both words' more unique (and thus **predictively-useful**) senses are more associated with other words. The word 'good' alone can appear everywhere, so has weak relationships everywhere, but still a strong relationship to other synonyms/antonyms on an evaluative ("good or bad", "likable or unlikable", "preferred or disliked", etc) scale.

All those random/non-predictive instances tend to cancel-out as noise; the relationships that have **some** ability to predict nearby words, even slightly, eventually find **some** relative/nearby arrangement in the high-dimensional space, so as to help the model for some training examples.

Note that a word2vec model isn't necessarily an **effective** way to predict nearby words. It might never be good at that task. But the **attempt** to become good at neighboring-word prediction, with fewer free parameters than would allow a perfect-lookup against training data, forces the model to reflect underlying semantic or syntactic patterns in the data.

(Note also that some research shows that a larger `window` influences word-vectors to reflect more topical/domain similarity – "these words are used about the same things, in the broad discourse about X" – while a tiny `window` makes the word-vectors reflect a more syntactic/typical similarity - "these words are drop-in replacements for each other, fitting the same role in a sentence". See for example Levy/Goldberg "Dependency-Based Word Embeddings", around its Table 1.)

Answer (score 0):

‘Embedding’ mean a semantic vector representation. e.g. how to represent words such that synonyms are nearer than antonyms or other unrelated words.

1. Embeddings algorithms like Word2vec maps entities be it e-commerce
   items or words (say in English language), to N-dimensional vectors.
2. Now since you have a mathematical representation of the entities in
   a Euclidean space, you can use associated semantics such as distance
   between vectors. e.g:
3. For a given item say ‘Levis Jeans’ recommend the most related items
   which are often co-purchased with it.
4. This can be easily done: search the nearest vectors to the vector of
   ‘Levis Jeans’, and recommend them. You will find that the nearest
   vectors correspond to items such as T-shirts etc., which are
   relevant to the Levis Jeans. Similarly it preserves
   distance/similarity between words e.g.: King - Queen = Man - Woman !
5. Yes, Word2vec captures such co-occurrance relationships, when
   mapping the items/words to vectors also called as ‘item/word
   embeddings’.

This is not specifically targeted to sentence embeddings but nevertheless here you get some crucial insights extremely relevant to the core logic behind embedding generation. [Read till the end](https://medium.com/@sapthrishi007/rediscovering-word2vec-for-e-commerce-item-embeddings-12754eaee8a2).